# Como definir o tamanho do VideoJS por porcentagem

Tags: css, reprodutor-de-video

Eu gostaria de definir o tamanho do VideoJS como por exemplo 40%m igual se definiria pelo CSS, e que quando seja alterado o tamanho do navegador, ela se adapte as novas porcentagens.

Até agora tenho isso

```
    <div class="videoContainer">
    <video id="player" height="281%" width="auto" controls class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"></video>
</div>
<script>
  videojs('player', {
    controls: true,
    nativeControlsForTouch: false,
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      ass: {
        'src': ["vjs/002.ass"],
        'delay': 0
      }
    },
    sources: [{"type": "video/mp4", "src": "vjs/002.mkv"}]
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode deixar ele com 100% e ajustar o container atravez de css:

```
<div class="videoContainer" style="width: 40%;">
    <video id="player" height="auto" width="100%" controls class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"></video>
</div>
<script>
  videojs('player', {
    controls: true,
    nativeControlsForTouch: false,
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      ass: {
        'src': ["vjs/002.ass"],
        'delay': 0
      }
    },
    sources: [{"type": "video/mp4", "src": "vjs/002.mkv"}]
  });
</script>
```

dessa forma, o video vai se ajustar conforme a div pai.